# How to change the width and keep things rtl?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.search_input',function(){ 
  $(this).animate({'width':'88%'});
});
```

```css
.search_box{
  margin: 10px 30px;
  direction: rtl;
   
}

.search_icon{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.search_input{
  padding-right: 55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search_box">
  <div class="search_icon">search</div> <!-- in reality it is a magnifier icon -->
  <input class="search_input" type="text" />
</div>
```

All I want to do is changing the position of the input. Noted that the word of `search` still should be in the right side of the input.

In other word, the input should be on the left side of the page and its `width` should be increased to the right side. again, always the word of `search` and input's direction should be on the right side (`rtl`) of the input.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tweaked a bit your snippet, is it what you're looking for?

You were applying `direction: rtl` to the whole `.search_box` div, that's why everything was on the right.

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.search_input',function(){ 
  $(this).animate({'width':'88%'});
});
```

```css
.search_box{
  margin: 10px 30px;
}

.search_icon{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-left: -55px;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.search_input{
  padding-right: 55px;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search_box">
  <input class="search_input" type="text" />
  <div class="search_icon">search</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, you should mark one of the answers as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by adding `text-align:left` property to the class search_box

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.search_input', function() {
  $(this).animate({
    'width': '88%'
  });
});
```

```css
.search_box {
  margin: 10px 30px;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align:left
}

.search_icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.search_input {
  padding-right: 55px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search_box">
<div class="search_icon">search</div>
<input class="search_input" type="text" />
  
  <!-- in reality it is a magnifier icon -->
  
</div>
```

Comment: `search` is out of `input` in your fiddle. it should always be on the right side *of the input*